# Endless Date List Generator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column from a table with a lot of different dates. I know how to generate a list of endless amount of weeks from any date BUT only one date that has to be hard coded in.

For example, if I throw in the date of '1/1/2000' and I want all the weeks after this date, then I get a column of every week after this date (see below):

Input field:

```
1/1/2000
```

Output column:

```
1/1/2000
1/8/2000
1/15/2000
1/22/2000
1/29/2000
```

...and so on

However, that is just one date. What I'm asking for is doing the same thing as above but showing the next X amount of weeks (in this example 5 weeks) for all the dates (see below):

Input column:

```
1/1/2000
1/1/2001
1/1/2002
1/1/2003
1/1/2004
```

Output column:

```
1/1/2000
1/8/2000
1/15/2000
1/22/2000
1/29/2000
1/1/2001
1/8/2001
1/15/2001
1/22/2001
1/29/2001
1/1/2002
1/8/2002
1/15/2002
1/22/2002
1/29/2002
1/1/2003
1/8/2003
1/15/2003
1/22/2003
1/29/2003
1/1/2004
1/8/2004
1/15/2004
1/22/2004
1/29/2004
```

The input column for this example is only 5 dates but in reality I have columns with hundreds of dates and it will not be just 5 weeks into the future, but more like 5 years into the future

**Using the explanation above, how do you generate this recurring list for all dates in a column?** Not just 5 weeks for the first date in the column (which I can do), but the next 5 weeks for each date in the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(date, v.dte) as dte, 1 as lev
      from (values ('2000-01-01'), ('2001-01-01'), ('2002-01-01'), ('2003-01-01'), ('2004-01-01')
           ) v(dte)
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 7, dte), lev + 1
      from cte
      where lev < 5
     )
select dte
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=580dd97f5606cc9f9852ac2c45476fad) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This works, and just to make it do exactly what I was asking for, I replaced the hardcoded dates with my own date column. Meaning replacing "values ('2000-01-01'), ('2001-01-01'), ('2002-01-01'), ('2003-01-01'), ('2004-01-01')" with "SELECT [date] FROM [mydatetable]" which makes this query dynamic.

Comment: @K.Ventura . . . Of course.  The `values()` clause is a stand-in for whatever source of dates you have.

Answer (score 1):

Gosh folks... don't use an rCTE (Recursive CTE) for such things (anything with an increment).  Even for small row counts, they're really obnoxious for resource usage and poor performance.  A well written WHILE loop will beat it for both.

There are methods that will blow the doors off of rCTEs, Loops, and other forms of RBAR.  The article is too long to repeat here but here's an article with some performance and resource usage measurements.

[Hidden RBAR: Counting with Recursive CTE's](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes)

**First, Create this Useful Function**

First of all, we're going to need the help of a tool that's been called the "Swiss Army Knife of T-SQL".  It's a "Tally Table" in the form of an iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function) built in a fashion first prescribed and described by Itzik Ben-Gan.  Here's the code for the function (fnTally).  The documentation is much longer than the code is.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Return a column of BIGINTs from @ZeroOrOne up to and including @MaxN with a max value of 10 Quadrillion.

 Usage:
--===== Syntax example
 SELECT t.N
   FROM dbo.fnTally(@ZeroOrOne,@MaxN) t
;
 @ZeroOrOne will internally conver to a 1 for any number other than 0 and a 0 for a 0.
 @MaxN has an operational domain from 0 to 4,294,967,296. Silent truncation occurs for larger numbers.

 Please see the following notes for other important information

 Notes:
 1. This code works for SQL Server 2008 and up.
 2. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's cascading CTE (cCTE) method for creating a "readless" Tally Table source of BIGINTs.
    Refer to the following URL for how it works.
    https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers
 3. To start a sequence at 0, @ZeroOrOne must be 0. Any other value that's convertable to the BIT data-type
    will cause the sequence to start at 1.
 4. If @ZeroOrOne = 1 and @MaxN = 0, no rows will be returned.
 5. If @MaxN is negative or NULL, a "TOP" error will be returned.
 6. @MaxN must be a positive number from >= the value of @ZeroOrOne up to and including 4,294,967,296. If a larger
    number is used, the function will silently truncate after that max. If you actually need a sequence with that many
    or more values, you should consider using a different tool. ;-)
 7. There will be a substantial reduction in performance if "N" is sorted in descending order.  If a descending sort is
    required, use code similar to the following. Performance will decrease by about 27% but it's still very fast 
    especially compared with just doing a simple descending sort on "N", which is about 20 times slower.
    If @ZeroOrOne is a 0, in this case, remove the "+1" from the code.

    DECLARE @MaxN BIGINT; 
     SELECT @MaxN = 1000;
     SELECT DescendingN = @MaxN-N+1 
       FROM dbo.fnTally(1,@MaxN);

 8. There is no performance penalty for sorting "N" in ascending order because the output is implicity sorted by
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
 9. This will return 1-10,000,000 to a bit-bucket variable in about 986ms.
    This will return 0-10,000,000 to a bit-bucket variable in about 1091ms.
    This will return 1-4,294,967,296 to a bit-bucket variable in about 9:12( mi:ss).

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - Unknown     - Jeff Moden 
        - Initial creation with error handling for @MaxN.
 Rev 01 - 09 Feb 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Modified to start at 0 or 1.
 Rev 02 - 16 May 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Removed error handling for @MaxN because of exceptional cases.
 Rev 03 - 07 Sep 2013 - Jeff Moden 
        - Change the max for @MaxN from 10 Billion to 10 Quadrillion to support an experiment. 
          This will also make it much more difficult for someone to actually get silent truncation in the future.
 Rev 04 - 04 Aug 2019 - Jeff Moden
        - Enhance performance by making the first CTE provide 256 values instead of 10, which limits the number of
          CrossJoins to just 2. Notice that this changes the maximum range of values to "just" 4,294,967,296, which
          is the entire range for INT and just happens to be an even power of 256. Because of the use of the VALUES
          clause, this code is "only" compatible with SQLServer 2008 and above.
        - Update old link from "SQLMag" to "ITPro". Same famous original article, just a different link because they
          changed the name of the company (twice, actually).
        - Update the flower box notes with the other changes.
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
GO
```

**Create 10,000 Rows of Test Data**

Now, let's create a little bit of test data... just 10,000 dates.  Along with the dates (and just to make it interesting), I've added a column for a contract length in weeks.

```
--===== Create the test data
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable
;
 SELECT SomeDate = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%DATEDIFF(dd,'2000','2021')),'2000'))
        ,ContractWeeks = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%53)*5
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM dbo.fnTally(1,10000)
;
```

---

**Use the Function to Make It Easy and Fast**

After that, the code for this problem is a breeze (and I added some columns just for demonstration purposes... remove what you don't want or need).

```
 SELECT  SomeDate
        ,Week#             = wk.N+1
        ,WeekStartDate     = DATEADD(wk,wk.N  ,tt.SomeDate)
        ,NextWeekStartDate = DATEADD(wk,wk.N+1,tt.SomeDate)
   INTO #Results
   FROM #TestTable tt
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(0,ContractWeeks) wk
;
```

**Performance**

Here's the stats on performance...

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 52, logical reads 33433, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#TestTable__________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000001E8'. 
Scan count 1, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 562 ms,  elapsed time = 576 ms.

(1320535 rows affected)
```

---

**rCTE Example**

Here's one version of an rCTE to "multiply" the starting date times the number of contract weeks and dump it into a table.

```
with cte as (
      select SomeDate as dte, 1 as lev
            ,ContractWeeks
      from #TestTable
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 7, dte), lev + 1
            ,ContractWeeks
      from cte
      where lev <= ContractWeeks
     )
select dte
into #Results1                            
from cte
order by 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

**Performance**
And here are the stats from that run... Compare the logical reads, CPU, and Duration.  This was for only 10,000 rows of input and only 1.3 million rows of output... same as the fnTally method...

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 7903617, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#TestTable__________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000001E8'.
Scan count 1, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6391 ms,  elapsed time = 6388 ms.

(1320535 rows affected
```

---

The bottom line here is that the rCTE

1. Used ~235 times or 23,500% more reads
2. Used  ~10 times or  1,000% more CPU
3. Took  ~10 times or  1,000% longer

Just say "NO" to rCTE's that increment (count).

Comment: I like how you say "only 10,000" rows and how your RBAR avatar adds to the post, and yes this is a much better solution to my problem and many other problems from other people where rCTEs would usually be used. However, as much as I would like to use this solution, sadly I have only read-only access to our server, so I am unable to create temp tables or custom functions, so the rCTE option works best for us. However, we have been getting performance issues on our servers, so I'm glad you gave me this better alternate solution that hopefully we can use one day when we really need to optimize.

Comment: Heh... thank you for the kind feedback but no excuses... please see the new post I've added. ; -)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, folks. The OP said the following in a comment on my previous post...

> However, as much as I would like to use this solution, sadly I have
>   only read-only access to our server, so I am unable to create temp
>   tables or custom functions, so the rCTE option works best for us.

No... the rCTE does NOT work the best for you even in this situation.

First of all, the use of the Temp Tables were just to build test data because I don't have access to the original tables posted by the OP.  They're just for testing... they're NOT a part of the solution.  Creating test data in this fashion is a VERY common practice among respondents and you simply need to recognize that fact and replace the name of the Temp Tables with the actual name(s) of your real tables.

The OP also wrote the following...

> However, we have been getting performance issues on our servers, so
>   I'm glad you gave me this better alternate solution that hopefully we
>   can use one day when we really need to optimize.

My take on this is... why wait?  Start now.  Submit the code for the fnTally function to the DBA with a justification as to why it should be a part of every database or at least included in an accessible utility database.  If the DBA is really on the ball, he may already have something like it (hopefully NOT based on an rCTE or While Loop) available and you just need to ask about it.

If that's not possible, then this problem can still be done to the same effect (high performance, short code, correct answers) but, since you can't do the "think OUTSIDE the box" thing,  you do have to take some time to "think INSIDE the box".

With that being said and with the understanding that you're going to need to change the name of the Temp Table to a real table (I used the Temp Table from my previous reply to test it with), the following slightly longer code uses similar cCTE (Cascading CTE) code to replace the fnTally function you can't make.

```
WITH 
     H1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))H0(N)) --16^1 or 16 rows
,    H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H1 a, H1 b, H1 c, H1 d, H1 e, H1 f, H1 g, H1 h) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
, Tally(N) AS (SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) - 1 FROM H8)
    SELECT  SomeDate
           ,Week#             = wk.N+1
           ,WeekStartDate     = DATEADD(wk,wk.N  ,tt.SomeDate)
           ,NextWeekStartDate = DATEADD(wk,wk.N+1,tt.SomeDate)
      FROM #TestTable tt
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (tt.ContractWeeks+1) N FROM Tally) wk
;
```

The bottom line is that it's pretty easy to avoid the horror of an rCTE that produces and incremental count even for something like this.  You just have to teach yourself how to think "INSIDE" the box you're limited to. :D